# gradle multiproject with different jdks, same source

Tags: android, spring, gradle

there are 3 projects in java: android app, backend api, backend server. I get dex errors in android studio. `com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)` because android will not work with 1.8 and spring needs 1.8.
The android app and backend server are both depending on the backend api. The app should be compiled with 1.7 and the backend server with 1.8.

That means the api should be compiled with 1.7 and 1.8.

My first try was to create 2 different artifacts, but it does not work.

This is my configuraton:

**settings.gradle**

```
include ':backend:api', ':app', ':backend:server'
```

**backend/api/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'


sourceSets {
    main1_7
}

compileJava {
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

compileMain1_7Java {
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

jar {
    archiveName = "api-jdk1.8.jar"
}

task jarMain1_7(type: Jar) {
    archiveName 'api-jdk1.7.jar'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

configurations {
    archives1_7
}

artifacts {
    archives1_7 jarMain1_7
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
// ...
android {
    // ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':backend:api', configuration: 'archives1_7')
    // ...
}
```

second try was to set api targetCompatibility to 1.7

**backend/api/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

but that gives me `javacTask: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8`.

I don't know how to solve it :(. Please help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: May be you should try to set sourceCompatibility to 1.7 too, for api, like it was made for android project

Comment: `:backend:api:compileJava` says `javacTask: target release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8`